# Trigger Visual Studio Online Release from TFS Build

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops, ms-release-management

I would like to trigger a release by utilizing the Release Management service hosted on Visual Studio Online. The build agent and controller are on a dedicated server which also contains the Release Management client (version 2013.4).
I've tweaked the build process template to allow triggering a release at the end of a successful build.
To initiate the release, the process template calls "ReleaseManagementBuild.exe" (apparently installed with the RM client) with the following parameters:

```
ReleaseManagementBuild.exe -tfs  https://MyServerName.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection -tp "My Project Name" -bd xxx -bn yyy -ts zzz -nologo
```

As a result I get the following error:

> ERROR: The TFS collection
>   (https://MyServerName.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection) does not
>   exist in the Release Management Server.

To narrow down the problem I've run the same command myself (not through the build process) on the build server and got the same error.
Triggering releases directly from the RM client works perfectly well.

Did anyone ever manage to achieve similar thing? What could be my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Release Management service currently in VSO only supports vNext release templates, which only support the [vNext REST API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/10/10/trigger-release-from-build-with-release-management-for-visual-studio-2013-update-3.aspx) for triggering releases. `ReleaseManagementBuild.exe` is only for agent-based releases.